# Opportunity Sharing Rules - Criteria-Based - Field Amount Not Available

Tags: opportunity, sharing-rule, criteria-based-sharing

I'm trying to create a sharing rule on Opportunity, criteria-base, and I want to add the field Amount to this rule.

[image]

Field Amount is not available and I'd like to know why.

Thank you all.

Comment: Please check whether the field Amount is formula field. Currently formula field is not supported in Criteria sharing rule criteria section.